# The multi-part identifier "ocl.id_Project" could not be bound

Tags: sql

This is my stored procedure :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetProjectDetails]
@id_Project varchar(50),
@Flag varchar(50)
as

set nocount on;

if @Flag='0'
begin
--distinct
select oci.id_Project, cm.Project_Name, 
    (select Project_Name from tp_Project_Master mc where mc.id_Project=oci.id_Project) as Project_Name, oci.Thumbnail_Image 
    from tp_Project_Master cm, tp_Project_images oci  
    where cm.id_Project=ocl.id_Project and oci.syncoperation<>'D' and oci.isdefault=1 order by oci.dateadded desc
end
```

But I am getting this error :

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetProjectDetails, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "ocl.id_Project" could not be bound.
```

I can't work out why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an object named **ocl** (ocl is mentioned in your where clause).  You do have an object named **oci**.  I'm guessing its just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `oci` to refer to the table, not `ocl`. Change this line and it should work:

```
where cm.id_Project=oci.id_Project
```